# Make mkhtmltopdf work on ovh

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, hosting

I'd like to use mkhtmltopdf in my project hosted on ovh with the perso offer. The fact is I don't know hot to install mkhtmltopdf on my sever. I don't have a ssh access (the offer doesn't content ssh access). The solution I found was to use mkhtmltopdf binaries but I can't manage to find them.

Here is my server config : [config](http://cluster015.ovh.net/infos/test.php54/)

I wish you'll be able to help me!

F. Cooper

PS: I'm quite sorry about my English expression but I'm not an English native. Please tell me if there is a spelling or grammar mistake.

Comment: Installing things on shared hosting is often impossable. You can try asking ovh to install it (maybe their customer service has improved), but for an extra euro a month you can rent a vps from ovh or others, with full access to install whatever you want. Oh and this question is off topic for SO, perhaps it should be on serverfault.com

Comment: Actually, looks like ovh vps start at the same price as the shared plan (£2.03 uk price)

Comment: I saw on ovh forum that binaries was allowed. The fact is I don't know where to find them..

Comment: Direct from the website? http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: I like the security of webhosting and I don't feel at ease to configure vps

Comment: Yes from the whhtmltopdf website. But which one do i have to chose?

Comment: That depends what flavour of linux the servers are running. Probably best to just call support

Comment: It's a Debian one but I can't use .deb, it is not binaries, it's installation packages

Comment: Not a debian user, but im fairly sure .deb files are just archives that can be extracted, such as with this tool: http://wobzip.org/

Comment: I had never noticed that before.. But it seems to work.

Comment: Great, hope you get it working

Comment: Thank your very much  user574632 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install binaries to your OVH's webhosting server.

- First get the binaries from: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html ->
  ([64bits
  Linux](http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz))
- Decompress it on your desk (Winrar, `tar xavf wkhtmltox*tar.xz`, or any `tar.xz` software ...)
- Send the extracted content to your [server via FTP](https://www.ovh.com/fr/g1374.mettre-mon-site-en-ligne)
- Execute the binary from your application